# How do I update a very old CentOS release (6.2) where yum won't work at all because of outdated openssl certificates?

Tags: centos, redhat, centos6, yum, rhel6

I have an old CentOS 6.2 machine and need to update a few packages on it (or many packages, I suppose).

However I can't do *anything* with yum because even after changing the repos to `vault.centos.org`, yum spits out this error whenever attempting to download any packages:

`[Errno 14] problem making ssl connection`

The usual solutions to this error are "update openssl or certificate bundles" but of course I can't do that because that requires yum.

I have already tried using `sslverify=0` in the repo file and `sslverify=false` in `yum.conf` to no avail.

Is there a manual way I can update these so I can start using yum again?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the certificate is not the problem but the supported TLS versions of the used SSL/TLS library. vault.centos.org for example is TLS1.2 only and your OS by default only supports TLS 1.0.

Therefore even disabling certificate checking won't help as the error is on protocol level.

I see two possible solutions:

1. Dowload the rpm packages of yum and it's dependencies manually on a different computer transfer them e.g. via USB Stick to the CentOS machine and there manually install them
2. If you have a second PC in your network with a newer OS install mitmproxy on it and on the CentOS machine use it as proxy. Install the mitmproxy root CA certificate or disable certificate checking. Mitmproxy should be able to translate the TLS versions so that yum can again connect to an update server.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem on a CentOS 6.6, and the solution that I found was:

1. Use mirrors provided by linuxsoft.cern.ch., i.e. replacing "baseurl=https://mirror.centos.org..." by "baseurl=https://linuxsoft.cenr.ch..." in your /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo. Be sure to use CentOS 6.10 mirror !
2. update openssl nssm curl (yum update ...)
3. You can switch back to vault.centos.org in your /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo.

Source: https://www.mark-gilbert.co.uk/fixing-yum-repos-on-centos-6-now-its-eol/

Comment: It bears repeating that CentOS 6 is end-of-life and has been for years.  Any maintenance effort is probably wasted because any "updates" you install only offer something slightly less out-of-date than what you have already been neglecting to update for years  and still won't make your system any less legacy.

Comment: My comment was a litte try to help the community. I totally agree with you ! But I have a client that is not yet ready to upgrade to a "modern" distro ...